# Linux oom-killer kills Jboss on Ubuntu Server (hosted Amazon EC2)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, memory, jboss, oom

We having some trouble with oom-killer and JBoss on Ubuntu Server. What I want to know is if there a way to avoid this with extra parameters passed to the JVM or to JBoss?

On the other hand, do you know guys how to add more RAM to an EC2 instance without changing the type of instance (actually it's a medium instance with only 1.7 GB)?

I'm posting the message I got from the command dmesg. What do these messages suggest?

Thank you!

```
[18272.090504] java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
[18272.090510] java cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[18272.090514] Pid: 1056, comm: java Not tainted 2.6.32-308-ec2 #16-Ubuntu
[18272.090516] Call Trace:
[18272.090526]  [<c0199538>] oom_kill_process+0xb8/0x1e0
[18272.090530]  [<c01996b1>] __out_of_memory+0x51/0xa0
[18272.090533]  [<c0199752>] out_of_memory+0x52/0xa0
[18272.090536]  [<c019be67>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x407/0x4a0
[18272.090540]  [<c019c04d>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x14d/0x160
[18272.090544]  [<c019e792>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xe2/0x200
[18272.090547]  [<c019e8d1>] ra_submit+0x21/0x30
[18272.090550]  [<c01979e8>] filemap_fault+0x3c8/0x3f0
[18272.090554]  [<c01af467>] __do_fault+0x47/0x630
[18272.090557]  [<c01b2b7f>] handle_mm_fault+0x1cf/0x5b0
[18272.090563]  [<c0155d2f>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xdf/0x110
[18272.090570]  [<c05370f9>] do_page_fault+0x119/0x340
[18272.090573]  [<c0536fe0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x340
[18272.090576]  [<c0535525>] error_code+0x3d/0x44
[18272.090578] Mem-Info:
[18272.090580] DMA per-cpu:
[18272.090582] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[18272.090584] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[18272.090585] Normal per-cpu:
[18272.090587] CPU    0: hi:  155, btch:  38 usd: 129
[18272.090589] CPU    1: hi:  155, btch:  38 usd: 143
[18272.090590] HighMem per-cpu:
[18272.090592] CPU    0: hi:  155, btch:  38 usd: 140
[18272.090594] CPU    1: hi:  155, btch:  38 usd: 113
[18272.090598] active_anon:208477 inactive_anon:208614 isolated_anon:32
[18272.090599]  active_file:187 inactive_file:147 isolated_file:0
[18272.090600]  unevictable:0 dirty:3 writeback:23 unstable:0
[18272.090601]  free:10840 slab_reclaimable:1277 slab_unreclaimable:1983
[18272.090602]  mapped:134 shmem:3 pagetables:0 bounce:0
[18272.090622] DMA free:6908kB min:76kB low:92kB high:112kB active_anon:508kB inactive_anon:712kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:16kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:16256kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:20kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:5 all_unreclaimable? yes
[18272.090626] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 696 1710 1710
[18272.090633] Normal free:35332kB min:3336kB low:4168kB high:5004kB active_anon:314428kB inactive_anon:314524kB active_file:732kB inactive_file:472kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:713224kB mlocked:0kB dirty:12kB writeback:92kB mapped:520kB shmem:4kB slab_reclaimable:5108kB slab_unreclaimable:7932kB kernel_stack:2456kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1957 all_unreclaimable? yes
[18272.090638] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 8111 8111
[18272.090645] HighMem free:1120kB min:512kB low:1724kB high:2940kB active_anon:518972kB inactive_anon:519220kB active_file:12kB inactive_file:100kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):128kB isolated(file):0kB present:1038292kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:8kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:334 all_unreclaimable? no
[18272.090649] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[18272.090652] DMA: 1*4kB 3*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6908kB
[18272.090684] Normal: 701*4kB 796*8kB 451*16kB 154*32kB 63*64kB 32*128kB 5*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 35332kB
[18272.090706] HighMem: 152*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 6*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1120kB
[18272.090716] 37223 total pagecache pages
[18272.090718] 36842 pages in swap cache
[18272.090720] Swap cache stats: add 5537986, delete 5501144, find 1747319/2163743
[18272.090721] Free swap  = 0kB
[18272.090722] Total swap = 917496kB
[18272.098867] 447488 pages RAM
[18272.098875] 263682 pages HighMem
[18272.098877] 10458 pages reserved
[18272.098878] 2162 pages shared
[18272.098879] 424736 pages non-shared
[18272.098883] Out of memory: kill process 26909 (run.sh) score 11830922 or a child
[18272.098898] Killed process 26939 (java)
```

Comment: I'd contact your provider directly to get more memory assigned!

Answer (score 3):

Linux itself [ran out of memory and killed Java](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Your possible solutions would be to make the application use less memory (you can set a memory limit on the Java VM), or increase the memory (EC2 has a high-RAM instance).

Comment: noted, must've glanced too quickly and missed a digit :)